# Converting Byte[] array to String

Tags: c#, encoding, arrays

I've tried this:

```
byte[] buffer = (byte[])mf.Input; 
    //Here, the buffer comes from a serial input
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)
string result2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
```

And some other methods like it. But it returns some strange characters... How do I really convert it?

This are the value I get: **"�??3?&?5?"**
and it was suppose to return me a `Card ID` value like `B54A7WQ912`
The buffer value is: ` buffer {byte[12]}

```
[0]168  
[1]63  
[2]18  
[3]63  
[4]21  
[5]...  
[6]....  
[7]....  
[8]...  
[9]...  
[10]...  
[11]...
```

each one with a value.

**UPDATE**
Now I'm able to `Write/Read` Into/From the `RFID` Mifare Card. But the special characters like `á,ã,à,è` is not showing, instead it's showing `?`. How may I fix it ? Thanks !

Obs: I'm using the methods above /\

Comment: That's the right approach, but if you haven't chosen the right encoding it won't work. Are you *absolutely* sure the original text isn't ANSI or ASCII?

Comment: What strange chars? Is it possible that buffer is partially filled?

Comment: What is the encoding used to transfer the string?

Comment: What encoding does the string come in as? What is the value of the array? What are the "strange characters"?

Comment: @MatthewWatson These are the strange characters `"�??3?&?5?"`
Updated my question

Comment: You should update your question to also include the given bytes and the expected output. `mf.Input` doesn't allow us to paste this into our own IDE.

Comment: I know C# and java are similar, but are they equal in this ? @ChrisStratton

Comment: Please post the code you have actually built and tried, with it's actual capitalization.

Comment: But it's on the question description... @ChrisStratton  
Isn't it ?

Comment: Also, are you sure you have the correct baud rate and serial word length settings?  I was sorry to see the RS232 comment edited out, as it was a clue to a potential source of issues.

Comment: I verified and the BaudRate is correct. here it compiled. You know that ´mf` is a particular class that I have the DLL of my `RFID reader` right ? That's why I have the `Input`property.

Comment: Try `string result = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);` and `string result = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer);` just in case...

Comment: the first 5 bytes that you have provided is neither utf8 nor ascii. provide some more data and expected value. card-id is 10 chars and we have 12 bytes. something doesnt add up.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Nothing... Unfortunatelly ;\

Comment: The data looks like garbage TBH... I'd look to the comms rather than the string conversion.

Comment: I'll check it now @MatthewWatson

Comment: That 63 actually _is_ ASCII for `?`.

Comment: Sorry all - my mistake.  Code looked so much like Java that I overlooked the C# tag.

Comment: Yeah it's not Unicode (UTF16) either.

Comment: My money is on wrong baud rate

Comment: Why did you rollback, @ChrisStratton ?

Answer (score 0):

`Encoding.GetString(byte[])` is the correct approach, you must choose the correct encoding and/or ensure that the data being sent to you is actually in the correct format.

Comment: wouldn't `Encoding.GetString(byte[],0,actualBytesInBuffer)` be a more correct approach   without assuming buffer is really filled?

Comment: There is no such method as `Encoding.GetString` only `Encoding.GetEncoding`

Comment: Update: I'm able now to Write/Read the Mifare RFID card. But when I read this ( the way I showed on my question), it does not show the characters like `é, ã, ó, ã á À à` you know ? How may I fix it ?

Comment: I guess the right one is this:  
`string result2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);`